# VSCode webview - remove default styles

Tags: visual-studio-code, webview, vscode-extensions

I'm building my own live html extension based on webview, however the rendered iframe always gets some default styles attached. Is there a way to remove the default styles?

Screenshot using Webview developer tools:
[image: screenshot]

My template doesn't have all these `<html style=` attributes except one:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" style="color: red">
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body style="background-color: white">
    ${text}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can ignore them, they are the theme colors, you can use them if you want to match the theme (background color). AFAIK you can't remove them

Comment: Sure, thanks, although these are further used and set into body, affecting the styles there: ```<body style="background-color: white" role="document" class="vscode-dark" data-vscode-theme-kind="vscode-dark" data-vscode-theme-name="Dark+ (default dark)" data-vscode-theme-id="Default Dark+">```. Wonder if I can get rid of these default styles.

Answer (score 1):

- Use a reset stylesheet. This will entirely reset the existing styling and allow you to build new styles on top - maybe `npm install normalize.css -D`.
- A point which runs perpendicular to your question: it's much more secure to do `npm install tailwindcss -D` in your extension, then you can load the styling using `script src=""` around `vscode.Webview.asWebviewUri`. The preview resources have to be bundled separately for sanity. It will still be much more secure than the external JS in your snippet.